# Javascript Collision Detection and Removal from Array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a version of space invaders in HTML, the collision detection between lasers and enemies does not work. I am not seeing any errors in the developer console.

```
// Returns whether or not an object is empty, i.e., does not exist. 
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function laserCollision() {
    for(var i = enemyArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(var j = playerLaserBeamsArray.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            // make sure not to access an object which does not exist.
            if(isEmpty(playerLaserBeamsArray[j])) break;
            if(isEmpty(enemyArray[i])) break;
            // check if laser beam is at correct y coordinate
            if(playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getTopY() >= enemyArray[i].getBottomY() && playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getBottomY() <= enemyArray[i].getTopY()) {
                // check if laser beam is between the enemy's furthermost left and right x-coordinates
                if(playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getLeftX() <= enemyArray[i].getLeftX() && playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getRightX() <= enemyArray[i].getRightX()){
                    score ++;
                    enemyArray.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The enemyArray is an array of enemy objects, and the playerLaserBeamArray is an array of laserbeam objects. Enemies are triangles and laserBeams are rectangles.
 Both objects have getLeft() and getRight() methods which return the left and right corners, and getTopY() and getBottomY() which return the furthermost y coordinates.

The github repo is:
https://github.com/Ruben-Krueger/Interstellar-Invaders

And can be played at:
https://ruben-krueger.github.io/Interstellar-Invaders/

Comment: `if(playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getLeftX() <= enemyArray[i].getLeftX() && playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getRightX() <= enemyArray[i].getRightX())` This condition doesn't look right. That is to say, it looks too far left.